# "getContentResolver().delete()" deleting every row instead of only one

Tags: android, database, android-contentprovider

I am trying to make my own ContentProvider and i am currently testing it in the same application. The insert method is working fine. But when i am trying to delete a row. It ends up deleting every row instead of just the one i selected. I am sending with both the clause to select on and the argument it is supposed to delete, so i don't understand why it deletes every row instead of just one.

In the KontaktCP it seems like the delete method doesn't think i am sending with an argument. Since it matches with MKONTAKT instead of KONTAKT and therefore deletes every row.

I have currently hardcoded the argument, since i am only testing. But i have checked that the _ID with value 1 exist in the database when i am running the program. and that the other _IDs is not 1.

Relevant code in MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{ 
    public static String PROVIDER="com.example.prosjekt3";
    public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://"+ PROVIDER + "/kontakt/");   

   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {       
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 

        //Delete values //          
        String [] arguments = new String[1];
        arguments[0] = "1";
        String selectionclause = "_ID = ?"; 
        getContentResolver().delete(CONTENT_URI, selectionclause, arguments); 
    }
// more code under here
}
```

Relevant code in KontaktCP

```
public class KontaktCP extends ContentProvider
{
    private final static String TABLE_kontakt="Kontakter";  
    public final static String PROVIDER="com.example.prosjekt3";
    public static final String KEY_ID="_ID";
    private static final int KONTAKT =1;
    private static final int MKONTAKT=2;    

    DBHandler DBhelper; 
    static SQLiteDatabase db;

    public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://"+ PROVIDER + "/kontakt");   
    private static final UriMatcher uriMatcher;
    static
    {
        uriMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
        uriMatcher.addURI(PROVIDER, "kontakt",MKONTAKT);
        uriMatcher.addURI(PROVIDER, "kontakt/#",KONTAKT);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreate()
    {   
        DBhelper=new DBHandler(getContext());
        db=DBhelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return true;    
    }
    public String getType(Uri uri) 
    {
        switch (uriMatcher.match(uri))
        {
            case MKONTAKT:return "vnd.android.cursor.dir/vnd.example.kontakt";
            case KONTAKT:return "vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.example.kontakt";
            default: return "Illegal uri"; // throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illeagal URI" + uri)
        }
    }
    @Override
    public int delete(Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) //matches MKontakt and deletes every row, instead of matching with KONTAKT
    {
        if (uriMatcher.match(uri)==KONTAKT)
        {
            db.delete(TABLE_kontakt, KEY_ID + "=" + uri.getPathSegments().get(1),selectionArgs);
            getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri,null);
            return 1;
        }
        if (uriMatcher.match(uri) == MKONTAKT)
        {
            db.delete(TABLE_kontakt,null,null);
            getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri,null);
            return 2;
        }
        return 0;   
    }
// more code under here
```

Relevant code in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" ></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.prosjekt3.permission"/>          
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>    
<permission android:name="com.example.prosjekt3.permission"/>
```

and:

```
    <provider android:name="com.example.prosjekt3.KontaktCP"
        android:authorities="com.example.prosjekt3"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" 
        android:readPermission="com.example.prosjekt3.permission"   
        android:writePermission="com.example.prosjekt3.permission">
    </provider>
```

Comment: can you try this `getContentResolver().delete(mybaseuri,"_ID ='"+arguments+"'",null);`

Comment: hello, thx for answering :) i am assuming mybaseuri is the same as CONTENT_URI in my code. i tried what you said twice but it's still deleting every row instead of only one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> so i don't understand why it deletes every row instead of just one

That's happening because of the `CONTENT_URI` that you use with the `delete()` method. Right now you pass a `CONTENT_URI` that corresponds to `MKONTAKT` in the `delete()` method so you'll delete everything. Instead the `CONTENT_URI` needs an id appended to it to match `KONTAKT`(as you declared it in the `UriMatcher`):

```
getContentResolver().delete(Uri.withAppendedPath(CONTENT_URI, "1"), selectionclause, arguments);
```

Comment: Hey, thx for answering :). when i am running your delete method the app crashes and i get an IllegalArgumentException.

 "java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.prosjekt3/com.example.prosjekt3.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Too many bind arguments.  1 arguments were provided but the statement needs 0 arguments."

Comment: @Madde If you're going to incorporate the id in the Uri then those selection arguments are useless: `db.delete(TABLE_kontakt, KEY_ID + "=" + uri.getLastPathSegment(), null);`(in the provider's delete() method).